# Integrate the function (indefinite)

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

See the thing is that even putting $\sin^2x + \cos^2x$ in the numerator and simplifying it, I am unable to proceed further after 2 simplification:
$(x\sin x/(x\sin x+ \cos x)^2) + ((x^2\cos^2x - x\sin x\cos x/(x\sin x+\cos x)^2)$
$$ \int\frac{(x^2)}{(x\sin x + \cos x)^2}$$
I think ILATE would be use but don't know at what point. Can anyone provide a better view. Many thanks.

Comment: "I think ILATE would be use" : what is ILATE?

Comment: Your posting is missing several details.
Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $(x\sin x+\cos x)'=x\cos x$ strongly suggests to multiply the numerator and denominator of the integrand in $\cos x$ as follows
$$
\int\frac{x^2}{(x\sin x + \cos x)^2}dx
{
=
\int\frac{x^2\cos x}{(x\sin x + \cos x)^2\cos x}dx.
}
$$
Integration by parts with $u=-\frac{x}{\cos x}$ and $v=\frac{1}{x\sin x + \cos x}$ as $\int udv=uv-\int vdu$ gives
$$
\int\frac{x^2\cos x}{(x\sin x + \cos x)^2\cos x}dx
{=
-\frac{x}{\cos x}\frac{1}{x\sin x+\cos x}+\int\left[\frac{1}{\cos x}+\frac{x\sin x}{\cos^2 x}\right]\frac{1}{x\sin x+\cos x}dx
\\=-\frac{x}{\cos x}\frac{1}{x\sin x+\cos x}+\int\frac{1}{\cos^2 x}dx
\\=-\frac{x}{\cos x}\frac{1}{x\sin x+\cos x}+\tan x+C.
}
$$
Therefore,

> $$\int\frac{x^2}{(x\sin x + \cos x)^2}dx=-\frac{x}{\cos x}\frac{1}{x\sin x+\cos x}+\tan x+C.$$